# How to reduce the time complexity of my search algorithm?

Tags: optimization, search, breadth-first-search

there is this problem in CodeWars that involves searching algorithms and since i'm still a beginner i had some difficulties trying to optimize my code, it's working correctly but i want it to be faster.
This is the problem if you would like to check it out : [Light Switch](https://www.codewars.com/kata/63306fdffa185d004a987b8e)

#### This is my first attempt using breadth-first search.

```py
# n is the number of lights
# corresponding_lights_list is the array representing relationships between lights and switches
# returns a boolean, represents whether it is possible to turn all the lights on.
 
def light_switch(n, corresponding_lights_list):
    lights = [0]*n
    oldlights = []
    queue = []
    while True:
        for s in corresponding_lights_list :
            newlights = [1 - lights[l] if l in s else lights[l] for l in range(n)]
            if newlights == [1]*n :
                return True
            if not (newlights in oldlights or newlights in queue) :
                queue.append(newlights)
        oldlights.append(lights)
        lights = queue.pop(0)
        if len(queue) == 0 :
            return False
```

#### I also tried searching in the two directions, so instead of reaching a final state you need to find a common state in the middle reached by both sides.

```py
from collections import deque
def light_switch(n, corresponding_lights_list):
    lights1 = [0]*n
    lights2 = [1]*n
    oldlights1 = []
    oldlights2 = []
    queue1 = deque()
    queue2 = deque()
    while True:
        oldlights1.append(lights1)
        oldlights2.append(lights2)
        for s in corresponding_lights_list :
            newlights1 = [1 - lights1[l] if l in s else lights1[l] for l in range(n)]
            newlights2 = [1 - lights2[l] if l in s else lights2[l] for l in range(n)]
            if not (newlights1 in oldlights1 or newlights1 in queue1) :
                queue1.append(newlights1)
            if not (newlights2 in oldlights2 or newlights2 in queue2) :
                queue2.append(newlights2)
            if newlights2 in queue1 :#or newlights2 in oldlights1 or newlights1 in queue2 or newlights1 in oldlights2 :
                return True
        lights1 = queue1.popleft()
        lights2 = queue2.popleft()
        if len(queue1) == 0 :
            return False
```

I would like from you guys to help me improve my code or even suggest a new approach, but please keep it as general as possible because i still want to solve this problem myself.

Comment: Maybe you can throw sufficient tricks at this overall approach, but these "light switch puzzels" have a classic and efficient approach based on Gaussian elimination (of a matrix over Z/2Z, not the regular old Real numbers). Do you want to optimize this anyway or go with that efficient approach

Comment: *"would also appreciate it if you could inform me about the time complexity of both programs"*: please make sure to only ask one question. Now it becomes a reason to close this question as too broad.

Comment: @harold I'll take a look at this new approach first, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), where each switch is an unknown (variable), and for each light you can formulate a constraint that essential says that the sum of *activated* switches that toggle that light must be odd (or otherwise put: the XOR of them should be 1).

For example, for this input:

```
[
  [0, 1, 2],    # switch 0 controls light 0, 1, 2
  [1, 2],       # switch 1 controls light 1, 2
  [1, 2, 3, 4], # switch 2 controls light 1, 2, 3, 4
  [1, 4]        # switch 3 controls light 1, 4
]
```

...we can define  as the state of the switch with index , and then write these XOR equations (one per light), which must be satisfied:

- <sub>0</sub> = 1
- <sub>0</sub> ⊕ <sub>1</sub> ⊕ <sub>2</sub> ⊕ <sub>3</sub> = 1
- <sub>1</sub> ⊕ <sub>2</sub> ⊕ <sub>3</sub> = 1
- <sub>2</sub> = 1
- <sub>2</sub> ⊕ <sub>3</sub> = 1

This can be represented as an extended matrix:

```
1 0 0 0 | 1
1 1 1 1 | 1
1 1 1 0 | 1
0 0 1 0 | 1
0 0 1 1 | 1
```

As these are booleans, you can also represent this matrix as a list of sets:

```
{0, 4}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
{0, 1, 2, 4}
{2, 4}
{2, 3, 4}
```

The values in each set represent switches, except for the value 4, which is a separate value to represent the last column in the extended matrix.

Then perform Gaussian elimination by XOR-ing rows (sets) with each other, to end up with a matrix where a switch is member of at most one row (set). Then there should be no other rows (sets) that are non-empty (as they may still contain 4): this represents an inconsistency and False should be returned in that case.

If you cannot make it work, here is a spoiler:

> `def light_switch(num_lights, corresponding_lights_list):
>      num_switches = len(corresponding_lights_list)
>      # Build extended matrix for Gaussian elimination. As the variables (switch states)
>      # are booleans, a matrix row can be represented with a set (of switches)
>      # The num_switches value represents the desired outcome by xoring the states
>      #      of the relevant switches (i.e. the light should be ON)
>      gauss = [{num_switches} for _ in range(num_lights)]
>      # Populate the matrix:
>      for switch, lights in enumerate(corresponding_lights_list):
>          for light in lights:
>              gauss[light].add(switch)
>      # Perform Gaussian elimination
>      light = 0
>      for switch in range(num_switches):  # iterate columns (switches)
>          # Find a constraint that involves this switch
>          i = next((i for i in range(light, num_lights) if switch in gauss[i]), -1)
>          if i == -1: # No constraint found for this switch: it is irrelevant
>              continue
>          # Swap constraint
>          gauss[light], gauss[i] = gauss[i], gauss[light]
>          selected = gauss[light]
>          # Make this the only constraint that involves the current switch
>          for other_light in gauss:
>              if switch in other_light and other_light is not selected:
>                  # Redefine constraint as a XOR of itself with the selected constraint
>                  other_light.symmetric_difference_update(selected)
>          light += 1
>      # Confirm there are no constraints without switches that must produce light
>      return not any(rule for rule in gauss[light:])`

Finally, there are Python modules that can perform Gaussian elimination for you, and if they are implemented in C, they will certainly do the job faster.

Comment: Thank you for your help,  I did take a look at the spoiler and tried to rewrite it myself and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code using Gaussian Elimination

```
def light_switch(n_lights, switches_lights) :
   n_switches = len(switches_lights)
   matrix = [{n_switches} for _ in range(n_lights)]
   for s in range(n_switches) :
      for l in switches_lights[s] :
         matrix[l].add(s)
   light = 0
   for s in range(n_switches) :
       selected = set()
       for l in range(light, n_lights) :
           if s in matrix[l] :
               if len(selected) == 0 :
                   matrix[light], matrix[l] = matrix[l], matrix[light]
                   selected = matrix[light]
               else :
                   matrix[l].symmetric_difference_update(selected)
       if len(selected) != 0 :
           light += 1
   return not any(l for l in matrix[light:])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).